# C++ Pointers and Memory Deallocation

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm less used to rigid type-checking and lower level stuff such as deallocation. Recently, while attempting to write something along the lines of

```
// Product is a struct I defined earlier, nothing fancy
vector<string, Product>::iterator it;
// Do some stuff with the iterator...
// And now I know I won't be using the iterator again
map<string, Product>::iterator it;
```

However, this yielded the error 'duplicate declaration of local variable "it"'. So my question then is simply, why did this happen? I researched memory deconstruction, but so far as I'm aware it's apparently impossible to deconstruct iterators because they're actually pointers? Does C++ really not allow you to use the same name for different variables if you know you won't need the old one again, or normally would you release them into memory?

Comment: This has nothing to do with memory allocation or anything like that. You are trying to declare two different variables in the same scope, and give them the same name; this is not allowed. Simply give them distinct names, or else limit them to distinct scopes.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: this must be the answer. Why don't you then post it as an answer?

Comment: Aside:  your understanding of iterators is wrong - they're not pointers, but they are made to LOOK like pointers.  (Pointer in C++ is a very specific thing)  You can let them go out of scope and they'll be deconstructed without any issue at all.

Comment: @UKMonkey `std::vector<T>::iterator` is *allowed to be* an alias for `T*`, which I would say is pretty pointer-like

Comment: @Caleth it isn't defined to be one though.  The fact that a pointer looks like a pointer and in the case of std::vector, happens to implement the operators correctly too is just convenient.  It could be an alias for T* in std::map too if all the memory was contiguous and the implementation could somehow meet all the other requirements!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `it` is in the same *scope*, it cannot be re-declared: variable *shadowing* does not apply in the same scope.

One way round this is to use scoping blocks:

```
// Product is a struct I defined earlier, nothing fancy
{
    vector<string, Product>::iterator it;
    // Do some stuff with the iterator...
    // And now I know I won't be using the iterator again
}

{
    map<string, Product>::iterator it;
    // However, this yielded the error 'duplicate declaration 
    // Not any more!
}
```

In C++ you actually only need one of the scoping blocks but that could be construed as an obfuscating asymmetry. Java attempts to sort this out but fails miserably in that you can remove the second pair but *not* the first!

Comment: This certainly helps with the issue, but could you add more about why C++ does this? Python and other languages allow you to re-declare variables using the same name, so what is the reasoning behind this feature?

Comment: @Griftor: Personally I can't see a reason: the redeclaration of a variable in the same scope could simply permanently shadow the previous one. Already the language provides no mechanism for accessing a shadowed variable within a function, so it's not as if this would create a new problem.

Comment: Having checked a few languages - C++, Java, and C# follow this, while Python, Ruby, and Javascript do not. Judging by the fact that the three that do are compiled, while the other three are interpreted, I'm guessing it has something to do with the compilation process?

Comment: @Griftor There's no reason why a compiled language couldn't allow the type change. It's opinion based, but I think it's because scripting languages are made to be more accessible - which means allowing the user to just say 'foo = 5' and 'foo = "5"' to potentially be used in the same way - meaning they're just not going to be strongly typed ever.  while compiled languages are made to be faster - so that you don't pay for what you don't use.

Comment: @Griftor If the type changed, then potentially so does the size of the instance. This is not a problem for  referenced-based languages, such as Python, but is for value-based languages such as C++, as the storage for instances is performed _once_ when the function is first entered.

Comment: Bathsheba's and Neil Butterworth's post and comment answer my question. Thank you both.

Comment: @NeilButterworth that's not an problem. Whatever an implementation does with inter-scope shadowing would be possible with intra-scope shadowing. You don't have one variable changing type, you have two variables (with potentially disjoint lifetimes)

Comment: @Caleth It might be possible (though I don't see how) but it would definitely be undesirable. For example, any pointers to the object would have to change their type too, which is not an issue if things are defined at different scopes.

Comment: @NeilButterworth you seem to be confusing the name `it` with the object it names.

Comment: @Caleth I wasn't referring directly to this answer, I was responding to the OP's first comment on it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth in python, you can re-use the name to refer to a different object (with a different type), in the same scope. A "variable" is the binding of a name to an object. `a = 1`, `b = a`, `a += 1` doesn't mutate the `1` that is bound to `b`

Comment: @Caleth I know all this - it's what my first comment here was about.

Comment: Everytime I ever saw these scoping blocks in c++ code, I always took them out.

Answer (score -4):

It doesn't matter what language you use, if you give two different variables the same name in the same scope (and they are meant to be different things) you will just [edit] confuse everyone who comes along after you (including in this case yourself). And that counts double for people who have to maintain your code.

Get out of that habit as soon as possible. It doesn't matter what the language offers you. Just don't do it.

Comment: Very generic recommendation without good explanation or actual details.

Comment: apart from most scripting languages including python which won't create 2 different variables but just change the type

Comment: of course it does matter what language you use. There is no nature law that would forbid to have a language that would allow code like this `int i = 5; /* .... */ int i = 7;`. For example by treating `int i=7;` as a new variable that happens to have the same name and by not allowing acces to the previous `i`. Of course that would be rather confusing, but my point is: it definitely does matter what language you use because it is only the language that makes up those rules

Comment: Thanks guys for the feedback. I've clarified my answer.